# Row selection and copying with a button

Tags: excel, button, vba

I am trying to use a button in Excel to copy a certain range of cells from the active workbook to another workbook. The copying works perfectly when I specify a fixed range for each button in its assigned Macro but I'm stumped as to how to use the same Macro on each button and for the button's row number to indicate the row of data to be copied.

Every row contains 6 or so cells with the 7th containing the button. When the user presses this button the 6 cells on the same row as the row containing the pressed button need to be copied.

I am a complete novice when it comes to VBScript but much googling has got me this far:

```
Sheets("SurfaceThreats").Range("A4:F4")Copy_
Sheets("ORBAT").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(x1Up).Offset(1,0)
```

Surely there is a more elegant solution than assigning a different, fixed range, Macro to every button.

Comment: Yes you could have only one button and then ask the user to select the row before pressing the button. You could also use a refedit control to let the user select the row. And then copy the relevant cells

Comment: Alternatively you could use `Application.Inputbox` as well to accept the row selection.

Answer (score 3):

See this screenshot

[image]

And this is the code for the `Select Row(s)` button

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Ret As Range, rng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Ret = Application.InputBox("Please select the row", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not Ret Is Nothing Then
        For Each rng In Ret.Rows
            '~~> Get the last row in sheets "ORBAT" where you want to copy
            With Sheets("ORBAT")
                lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            End With

            '~~> Copy the rows
            Sheets("SurfaceThreats").Range("A" & rng.Row & ":F" & rng.Row).Copy _
            Sheets("ORBAT").Cells(lRow, 1)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a generic button handler, but you can dynamically create the buttons and the macros to handle them. But it's quite a lot of work and you'll have to start creating macros dynamically. (this can cause problems with anti-virus software sometimes i think).

You could use the `Worksheet_OnBeforeDoubleClick` event to create "fake" buttons

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You Clicked " & Target.Address
        ' call your generic handler here passing the Target.Address or Target.Row
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Using this code, if you double click any cell in the "A" column you'll get a message box saying what cell you clicked.

Its not the best of ideas, some users might not understand that it is a button.